# Trying to figure out Liquibase rollback with SQL

Tags: sql, liquibase

Trying to figure out how rollbacks work with formatted SQL and Liquibase.

Working from the quickstart on the Liquibase site, I was able to create a table in my database.  Then started working on the rollback.  Just as a manual test, once my table was created, I tagged the change in the DATABASECHANGELOG table.  Ran Liquibase rollback `<mytag>` and it said it completed it successfully, but the table wasn't modified.

```
--liquibase formatted sql
--changeset user:1
create table addresses (
address VARCHAR(45),
city VARCHAR(45),
zip VARCHAR(10)
);
--rollback drop table addresses;
```

Liquibase said the rollback completed successfully, but the table wasn't dropped.

Comment: You could try to run `updateSQL` instead of `update`. Then liquibase will put out the SQL on the terminal instead of directly on the database. 
Then apply the resulting SQL statements manually to the DB and see if that works. That way you could exclude problems outside of liquibase scope.

Answer (score 0):

The tagging concept in Liquibase seems to confuse many people. Tagging is used to mark a known good state, so if you tagged it after deploying a change that created a table, and then said rollback to that tag, it did things 'correctly' in its way of thinking.

Here is the tiny bit of documentation on that (I added the emphasis on *after*):

> **Tag**
>
> Specifying a tag to rollback to will roll back all change-sets that
>   were executed against the target database *after* the given tag was
>   applied. See the “command line” documentation for how to tag your
>   database.

To test the rollback of the table in your example, you would need to use the `rollbackCount` command or the `rollbackToDate` command.